# Red Hat Process Automation Manager Database Sizing?

Tags: jboss, redhat, jbpm, redhat-bpm

How would one go about sizing a data for Red Hat Process Automation Manager (jBPM)? All to documents I have read state you can hook it up to a database (mySQL mostly) but don't give any inclination to default sizing anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The size of the database will be dependent on the your business requirement or the usages. It will vary as per your implementation.
- If the database tables are growing infinitely then you can remove the historical data/clean history tables. Red Hat Process Automation Manager (RHPAM) provide feature to schedule a job and clear the historical data periodically.
- Configure a "LogCleanupCommand" job to clear the historical data.